# Method 'delete' is deprecated

Tags: delete, methods, deprecated

phpstorm IDE saing that method 'delete' is deprecated. Is there any alternatives?

```
public function deleteVoucherStatus($entity_id)
    {
        $voucherStatus = $this->voucherStatusModelFactory->create();
        try {
            $voucherStatus->setId($entity_id)->delete();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }

        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code ?

```
 public function deleteVoucherStatus($entity_id)
    {
        $voucherStatus = $this->voucherStatusModelFactory->create();
        try {
        $voucherStatus->load($entity_id)->delete();         
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }

        return true;
  }
```